# Java: How to read file from different module?

Tags: java, file, maven

I have a project with multiple maven modules

```
project/pom.xml
       /external_services/pom.xml
                         /ifs/pom.xml
                             /src/test/java/
                                           /MockIFSClient.java
                                           /IFSClientTest.java
                             /src/test/java/resources/sample.json
       /inventory/pom.xml
                 /business/pom.xml
                             /src/main/java/InventorySummary.java
                 /services/pom.xml
                             /src/main/java/InventorySummaryResource.java
                             /src/main/test/InventorySummaryResourceTest.java
```

**MockIFSClient** access `sample.json` as

```
try {
    inventoryPriceDetails = mapper.readValue(new File(getClass().getResource("/getInventoryAndPriceResponse.json").getPath()), new TypeReference<List<InventoryPriceDetail>>() {
    });
} catch (final IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("could not read resource :" + e.getMessage());
}
```

so **IFSClientTest** runs fins since they are in same package.

**Problem?**
`InventorySummaryResourceTest` calls `MockIFSClient` which tries to access the same code, but now it fails as

```
could not read resource :file:/Users/harith/IdeaProjects/inventory_api/external_services/ifs/target/ifs-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar!/sample.json (No such file or directory)
```

**services/pom.xml** has dependency as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.org.project.external_services</groupId>
    <artifactId>ifs</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Question**

What change do I make to

```
new File(getClass().getResource("/getInventoryAndPriceResponse.json").getPath())
```

so that it can be accessed from different modules as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer helped me getting it right

[How to really read text file from classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

I changed my code then to

```
inventoryPriceDetails = mapper.readValue(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/getInventoryAndPriceResponse.json"), new TypeReference<List<InventoryPriceDetail>>() {});
```